# Does git log list log history of all the local branch? If so is there any way to list log of one branch

Tags: git

The `git log` seems to list the log history of all local branches

Is there any way to list log of only one particular branch?

Comment: No, it's the contrary. `git log` lists current branch's history only, whereas `git log --all` lists commits taking every branch into account. Could you give out the details of the tests which led you to this unexpected conclusion?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you answer it ? I will check it then :)

Comment: Curious, why did you think `git log` shows history of all branches?

Comment: I usually used an alias of log with `--all`, and I did not notice the use of `--all`

Comment: @Rui That's a common one, thanks for the feedback anyway.

Comment: @RomainValeri you can edit the answer here. Then I will vote and you get the bonus

Comment: @Rui Kind of you but it's unnecessary. Take care.

Comment: @Rui Did you try to use `git log particular_branch` (eg `git log master`)?

Comment: @ThanLUONG no, but good to know :) Thanks a lot. You can also answer here and I give the bonus

Comment: In `git log [<options>] [<revision range>] [[--] <path>…​]`, which does the `particular_branch` correspond to?

Comment: You can see an example: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-codegitlogmaster--not--remotesmastercode.

Comment: To my knowledge, we are allowed to specify a particular branch. When we do not specify, by default we will choose the local branch we are on.

Comment: @ThanLUONG Thanks a lot

Comment: I vote because your question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could view list log of one particular branch using `git log particular_branch` (eg `git log master`).